# how to implement multiple queues in Ns-2

Tags: ns2

In my project I want to differentiate the `incoming traffic` into multiple classes like `critical`, `normal`, `delay sensitive` packets,

**want to queue each type of packet in separate queues having different priority,**

I define highest priority in the order :

1. Critical packets,
2. delay sensitive packets
3. normal packets.

how i can do it in NS-2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Queue/dsRED` queue from the `diffserv` model.

You can see example scripts in

```
$NS_HOME/tcl/ex/diffserv/
```