# How to introduce new queue command in ns2?

Tags: queue, tcl, ns2

This is not a duplicate of [how to implement multiple queues in Ns-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612114/how-to-implement-multiple-queues-in-ns-2/15613243).

- Goal - I wanted to change internals of how queues behave without disturbing the existing queues.
- What I did - So I duplicated Queue, DropTail, PriQueue and some other classes on which these depend in corresponding headers, cc files as Queue1, DropTail1, ... . Rebuilt ns2 application.
- My tcl code uses `Queue/DropTail/PriQueue` as `ifqType` and so I changed it to `Queue1/DropTail1/PriQueue1`
- When I did `ns myfile.tcl`, it shows me below error:

```
num_nodes is set 10
invalid command name "Queue1/DropTail1/PriQueue1"
    while executing
"Queue1/DropTail1/PriQueue1 create _o20 "
    invoked from within
"catch "$className create $o $args" msg"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$className create $o $args" msg] {
if [string match "__FAILED_SHADOW_OBJECT_" $msg] {
delete $o
return ""
}
global errorInfo
error "class $..."
    (procedure "new" line 3)
    invoked from within
"new $qtype"
    (procedure "_o14" line 11)
    (Node/MobileNode add-interface line 11)
    invoked from within
"$node add-interface $chan $propInstance_ $llType_ $macType_  $ifqType_ $ifqlen_ $phyType_ $antType_ $topoInstance_  $inerrProc_ $outerrProc_ $FECProc_"
    (procedure "_o3" line 83)
    (Simulator create-wireless-node line 83)
    invoked from within
"_o3 create-wireless-node"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $self create-wireless-node $args"
    (procedure "_o3" line 23)
    (Simulator node line 23)
    invoked from within
"$ns node"
    ("for" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } { incr i } {
        set mnode_($i) [$ns node]
}"
```

- I understood that, my changes needs to be reflected somewhere else other than just C++ codes.

1. What other changes needs to be done to my codes?
2. Is there any step-by-step guide to allow new queue types?

Comment: Is this about how to tell the code where your class is? Or is it that the name is simply not what you thought it was?

Comment: @Shawn, No; Those are three different classes first one being super class and then child, grand-child

Comment: @Donal Fellows, am unsure about your words. But, How'd ns2 executable get to know about my new queues?

Comment: You should edit your question to include a [mcve], not just error messages.

Comment: @Shawn, I have classes by those names on C++ side. But it's not enough to use them in ´ifqType´ ! What extra needs to be done?

Comment: @Shawn, Think of the situation this way: am able to use `Queue/DropTail/PriQueue` as `ifqType` but why not `Queue1/DropTail1/PriQueue1`?

Comment: @Shawn, Yes, what're the steps to introduce a command or class with that name?